# Problems trying to install APK on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I'm trying to test my app on a Kindle Fire.  I hacked the .ini and .inf files as per the book.  My computer sees the kindle but I dismounted (ejected) the kindle and hit the disconnect button on the kindle as per the book's instructions.

I'm new to eclipse but I set the run configuration to "device" and tried to run it.

I got the following errors the console:

> [2012-08-15 17:51:19 - PS] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>
> [2012-08-15 17:51:19 - PS] Please check logcat output for more details.
>
> [2012-08-15 17:51:19 - PS] Launch failed on device: 780C002600000001

logcat is huge.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY, this is the error. are you using any jar files or some special SDK like Maps?

Comment: Make sure your target is "Android X.X" and not "Google APIs".

Comment: whats is "the book"? there are lots of android programming books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test application has a `<uses-library>` element that references a library that the Kindle Fire does not have. Most likely, you are trying to install an application that uses the Maps add-on, and the Kindle Fire does not have Google Maps.